# React event for removing Alert messages?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, events, alert

Bootstrap has this nice alert facility https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/ and I have build my React alert component around Bootstrap Alert like (partial view):

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <div class={this.getAlertClasses()} style={this.getAlertStyle()} role="alert">
                {this.getMessage()}
              </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I have global React state which is read by my Alert component using:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        orderCommandState: state.orderCommandState,
        orderCommandMessage: state.orderCommandMessage
    };
};
```

And my Order form has actions/commands (liek order, ship, cancel, save, recalculate) that execute some business logic and also - as the last procedures in my command - also updates the values of `state.orderCommandState` and `state.orderCommandMessage`. Alert component is sitting on my Order page and React automtically propagates the updated state variables to Alert component and Alert component displays state and message. That is fine.

My question is - **does React component have some suitable events in which I can make Alert message invisible when it is not relevant any more** - that means when the user restarts data editing, e.g. when she clicks in some editable field, or when she clicks on some button and so on. What is React event that can catch all those different user interaction events that happen after execution of one command and after display of alert?

Answer (score 1):

you can use onBlur event:

```
class YourContainer extends React.Component {
            constructor(){
                this.state = { showAlert: false }
                this.alertRef = React.createRef();
            }
            render(){
                { this.state.showAlert && // set to true when alert is needed
                    <div 
                      tabIndex="0"
                      className="your-alert-component" 
                      ref={this.alertRef}
                      onBlur={() => this.setState({showAlert: false})}
                    >
                       ..message
                    </div>
                }
            }
            componentDidUpdate()}{
                this.alertRef.current && this.alertRef.current.focus();
            }
        }
```